# How to get the permutation of an array without changing the order of its values?

Tags: ruby, permutation

For this array: `a = [8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15]`, how can I get all sub-arrays of length three, in the fashion of a sliding window, without disturbing the order of the values.?

For example, the result should be: `[[8,2,22],[2,22,97],[22,97,38],[97,38,15]]`

Comment: Ruby's `Array#permutation` already returns values according to the source's order.

Comment: @Alexander, that's irrelevant, because the OP's question has nothing to do with permutations (in view of the desired result). :-)

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are asking about permutations, but your example results are not permutations. What is it *exactly* that you want?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Instead of picking apart the usage of the word permutation, wouldn't it be more constructive and to the spirit of StackOverflow to suggest an edit? Many people, including the ones who responded to the accepted answer, understood what is it *exactly* I wanted.

Comment: Well, it is hard from just a single example to judge what it is that you want. I *could* edit the question and say that you are looking for a sliding window half the size of the original array, but I have no idea if that is correct or not. It could also be a sliding window 1/60th the sum of values of the array. Also, to further the confusion, not only does your expected output not match up with your question, you also accepted an answer whose output neither matches up with your question nor with your example output. (In fact, the accepted answer doesn't even work at all.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag It does. Read the comments. He just didn't add .to_a to it.

Comment: It is indeed in the spirit of SO for someone other than the asker to edit a question to make it clearer.  It is even more in the spirit of SO to make the edit yourself, when it is your question and you know what is wrong with it.

Comment: @WayneConrad Indeed it would be, when I know what is wrong with it. Not a single person in this thread has enlighten me with their wisdom to the precise vocabulary that would suit this question. There are, however, many responses under the accepted answer who knew what I was asking without being condescending.

Comment: @KaMok I apoligize--I thought you did know how to make it clearer.  I've just made an edit that I hope helps.  I realized, while editing, that I found it somewhat difficult to describe in words what it is you want, so you deserve my apology all the more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a parameter for  like this to achieve

`a.each_con(3)`

This returns an Enumeration which you may iterate over.  To turn the Enumeration into an array, call the to_a method:

`a.each_cons(3).to_a`

Comment: that wont give his requested answer though

Comment: Can you share the correct answer and please correctly point out how my answer is different?

Comment: all i'm saying is `a.permutation(3).to_a != [[8,2,22],[2,22,97],[22,97,38],[97,38,15]]`

Comment: I have also rectified the answer above. 
`answer = []
answer + a.each_con(3).to_a`

Comment: a.each_cons(3).to_a is the answer

Comment: nikkypx, have you tried executing `a.permutation(3).to_a #=> [[8, 2, 22], [8, 2, 97],..., [15, 38, 97]]`? Note  `a.permutation(3).to_a.size #=> 120`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
def ordered_permutations(array: [1,2,3], length: n)
  array = array.dup
  [].tap do |result|
    (array.count - (length - 1)).times do
      result << array[0..(length-1)]
      array.shift
    end
  end
end

p ordered_permutations(array: a, length: 3)
```